# Problemas al crear una lista dentro de una función anidada

Tags: python, funciones

Quiero crear una función que al ingresarle un campo de fecha (datetime), me indique la suma total de otro campo ('ventas') por año. Por ejemplo que al ingresar el campo 'date' de mi DF a la función, me arroje el total de ventas por año:

[image: mi data frame]

```
def time(x): 
    lista=[]
    for i in df[x].dt.year:
        if i not in lista:
            lista.append(i)
            def inner(*args):
                lista_2=[]
                for j in args:
                    lista_2.append(df[df[x].dt.year==j].weekly_sales.sum())
                return lista_2 
    return inner(lista)
```

El problema es que me arroja =0

Hice un código similar (la misma estructura) para que me entregue las medianas de los campos float e integer, y ese funciona sin problema:

```
def t(df):
    lista=[]
    for i in df.columns:
        if df[i].dtypes == 'int64' or df[i].dtypes == 'float':
            lista.append(i)
            def inner(*args):
                lista_2=[]
                for j in args:
                    lista_2.append(df[j].median())
                return lista_2                
    return inner(lista)
```

Favor si me pueden ayudar con ésta duda :) !!! Quizás lo que estoy haciendo no es lo optimo, pero quiero al menor arreglar la función, ya que estoy recién aprendiendo.

Muchas gracias !!!!

Comment: Y por que no usas las funciones propias de pandas?. Por ejemplo tu código de la mediana se reduce a 1 línea `df.apply(lambda col: col.median() if col.dtype in ('int64', 'float') else None).dropna()`. Y para lo que quieeres, si entendí bien, se puede lograr con `df.groupby("date").sum(numeric_only=True)`. Solo faltaría especificar la columna ventas, la cual no veo en tu ejemplo.

Comment: Hola Christian!!!    Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Efectivamente sabia que había una forma más fácil de hacerlo para el tema de las medianas. Me sirvió perfecto. Pero en el caso del groupby, el detalle que tengo es que quiero agrupar por año, no por fechas distintas. Sé que el df tiene 3 años, (2010,2011,2012) y quiero que me entregue los totales por año de las 'weekly_sales'. Quiero obtener una función genérica, que sea independiente de la cantidad de años que pueda tener el df y no quiero hacerlo creando una columna nueva llamada 'año. Haber si puedes ayudarme... Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pues sí, puedes agrupar por periodos en pandas. Ahora hago una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Como decía en mi comentario. Pandas trae consigo muchas funcionalidades que te permiten ahorrar líneas de código y tiempo con sus funciones vectorizadas.

Una solución al problema de la mediana es el uso del método `apply` que aplica una función al recorrer el dataframe

```py
df_mediana = df.apply(lambda col: col.median() if col.dtype in ('int64', 'float') else None).dropna()
```

Lo que hace el código es recorrer las columnas del dataframe. A cada columna se le aplica la función lambda que primero valida el tipo de la columna, en caso sea `int64` o `float64` aplicará la función `median` a la serie y retornará el valor, en caso no lo sea retornará `None`. Esto nos da como resultado una serie con los valores, pero como vamos a tener valores `NaN` los eliminamos con el método `dropna`.

Otra opción sería aplicar directamente la función `median` al dataframe. Pero antes habiéndolo filtrado según el tipo de dato de las columnas.

```py
columnas_numericas = df.select_dtypes(include=[int, float])
df_mediana = columnas_numericas.median(numeric_only=True)
```

Para el siguiente caso de agrupar por año y sumar todos los valores del año podemos usar la función `groupby` que nos agrupará según la coolumna que especifiquemos, pero como queremos que agrupe por cada año y no por cada fecha en sí deberemos recurrir a la función `pd.Grouper` la cual permite especificar un periodo para agrupar valores.

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df_por_anio = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="1Y")).sum(numeric_only=True)
```

A la función `pd.Grouper` le pasamos como `key` el nombre la columna que queremos agrupar y para especificar la frecuencia usamos el parámetro `freq` y le damos como valor `1Y` para que agrupe por año. Finalmente usamos la función sum para sumar todos los valores de cada una de las columnas y especificamos el parámetro `numeric_only=True` para que solo sume las columnas que son números.

En tu pregunta indicas que quieres sumar todas las ventas por año, pero no se aprecia ninguna columna `venta`. Pero igual te dejo aquí cual sería elprocedimiento.

```py
# creamos un dataframe
data = {
    'store': [1, 1, 1 ,1, 1],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'department': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'date': ['2010-02-05', '2010-03-05', '2010-04-02', '2010-05-07', '2011-02-03'],
    'weekly_sales': [24924.50, 21827.90, 57258.43, 17413.94, 1010.80],
    'is_holiday': [False, False, False, False, False],
    'temperature_c': [5.728, 8056.0, 16817.0, 22528.0, 4900.1],
    'fuel_price_usd_per_l': [0.679, 0.693, 0.718, 0.749, 0.744],
    'unemployment': [8106, 8106, 7808, 7808, 1010],
    'venta': [800, 840.2, 890.32, 1000.1, 8080.2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convertimos la columna date a valores datetime
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# obtenemos las columnas que nos interesa que serian date y venta
df_venta_por_anio = df[["date", "venta"]].groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="1Y")).sum(numeric_only=True)

print(df_venta_por_anio)
```

Comment: Christian!!! Muchisimas gracias, la verdad que con lo que me comentas he aprendio un monton. No conocia la funcion pd.Grouper, la cual comenzaré a utilizar desde ya!! Te agradezco un monton... un abrazo  :)